# How to compare POST response to array values?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having difficulty comparing the $_POST from a user input to a set of array values.

I've set the following variable ...

```
$response = $_POST['answer'];
```

... and selected a range of possible correct answers and stored them in an array ...

```
$solutions = array('answer1','answer2','answer3');
```

I've tried checking/comparing like this ...

```
if (value($response) !==  ($solutions)
{$error['result'] = "Wrong answer.";}
```

I know it's the line `if (value($response) !==  ($solutions)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in_array()` is your friend:

```
$correct = in_array($response, $solutions);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare array values;
as **harakiri** wrote **in_array()** is your friend.

However if you want to compare array keys, you have to use;
**array_key_exists()**

I would like to warn you tho, if your array contains a lot of information checking it with in_array() will slow you down.

Instead you will have to go with isset() to check if it is set, it is much faster than in_array().

Answer (score 0):

```
$answer = false; 

foreach ($solutions as $sol)
{
    if ($sol == $_POST['answer'])
    {
        $answer = $sol;
        break; 
    }
}

if ($answer)
{
    //GOOD
}
else
{
    $error['result'] = "Wrong answer."
}
```