# How to compare $_POST values with array values in Ajax and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Let's say I have one array with 10 elements and 10 inputs in a form.
How would I compare on links click first value of the array with the value in the first input with Ajax? And so for the next ones.

I have to mention that I can put yes or no in the empty values of every input.

```php
$array = array(
      1 => 'yes',
      2 => 'no',
      3 => 'yes'
);
```

```html
<form action='' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='input1' value=''>
  <input type='text' name='input2' value=''>
  <input type='text' name='input3' value=''>
  <a href='' class='yes'>Yes</a>
  <a href='' class='no'>No</a>
</form>
```

Comment: just post the form and compare it at php.

Comment: How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @ionut take a look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695848/how-to-compare-post-response-to-array-values

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't help me. I want to do this with AJAX and compare each and individually value from post with value from array.

Comment: Also, On first click I want to compare the first post value with the first array value, on second click I want to compare the second post value with the second array value ... and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as following

```
<script>
function comp()
{
    var jqueryarray = <?php echo json_encode($myvalues); ?>;
    var inputVal1 = $('#input1').val();
    var inputVal3 = $('#input2').val();
    var inputVal3 = $('#input3').val();

    // you can now compare inputVal1 or inputVal2 or inputVal3 with array jqueryarray which we have created from php array
}
</script>

<?php $myvalues = array(1 => 'yes', 2 => 'no', 3 => 'yes'); ?>

<form action='' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='input1' id='input1' value=''>
  <input type='text' name='input2' id='input2' value=''>
  <input type='text' name='input3' id='input3' value=''>
  <a href='' class='yes' onclick='comp()'>Yes</a>
  <a href='' class='no' onclick='comp()'>No</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, but I have an external js file. And dinamic input ids and multiple inputs and I want to do this with AJAX.